# QTableWidget of one window to other window

Tags: qt-creator, qtablewidget, qt-signals

I want to show my table which is in mainWindow to other window. I stuct there. Please give me a proper solution in python.

I am doing this in QT Creator. I have tried slots and signals but can't do what I want.